# Why Continous Variable Buckets Overfitting model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, xgboost, overfitting

I have a continuous (high cardinal discrete) variable 'numInteractionPoints' in my dataset during training model - I binned this feature in order to avoid overffing , first top bar chart is from training and second bar chart is from testing for this binned feature. Both datasets has same distribution as per following bar graph

[image]

this is how i created bin for this feature

i converted variable 'numInteractionPoints' into bins using simple bin method based on visual analysis

```
bins = [0, 6, 12, np.inf]
names = ['0-6', '6-12','12+']

train_data['numInteractionPointsRange'] = pd.cut(train_data['numInteractionPoints'], bins, labels=names)
train_data['numInteractionPointsRange']=train_data['numInteractionPointsRange'].astype('object')
```

in both cases when i include raw variable numInteractionPoints without bin and with above defined bucket the overall F1 score of model decrease on test data from 0.47 to 0.33 for a class 1. On validation dataset it is giving 0.47 while on test it gives 0.33 with or without bins

[image]

Any idea please what i am missing? This behavior is in both algo Xgboost and catboost, target class is highly imbalanced and i am controlling it Xgboost parameter scale_pos_weight. Why model overfitting due to defined buckets , as you can see above bar chart distribution of both dataset are same

Comment: Is this the only independent variable?  Maybe this one is not responsible for the overfitting...

Answer (score 1):

**When you use buckets you lose some information.** Basically you assume the relationship between the variable and the target is flat within the interval. When this is probably not the case. This is point #3 on Frank Harell's [list](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous) of reasons why you generally shouldn't categorise at all.

More specifically, 80% of your instances seems to be in one bucket. That mean your algo can't learn what happen inside this bucket. **As a starting point you may use more buckets to check if that was the problem**. More convoluted techniques would include splines to smooth the response (removing noise help not learning from it).  Honestly given that you work with a tree like algo (Xgboost) you should probably let it choose optimal splits instead of enforcing some splits trough variable categorisation. That is : **don't use a priori variable categorisation at all**, enforce the absence of overfitting trough other parameters (tree depht at least) and if you really need category use those found by the algo.

Edit: re-reading your question it seems that you are overfitting in both case... **the solution might be more about tuning your xgboost parameters.**